NVDA doesn't read aria-label / aria-labelledby on hover
I need to add an additional text to <a> tag for screen readers. Unfortunately, I discovered that the NVDA reader does not read either aria-label or aria-labelledby when I hover over the element.
It reads additional text when I move with arrows around the page, but I need it to work on hover
The code I tested looks like this:
<a href="#" id="btn" role="button" aria-labelledby="btn text">
    Find Out More
    <span id="text" class="visually-hidden">about [slide title]</span>
</a>


<a href="#" aria-label="Find Out More about [slide title]">Find Out More</a>

Currently NVDA only reads the content of  "Find out more" on hover and ignores both aria-label and aria-labelledby. Unfortunately I can't remove "Find Out More" from the tag, it needs to be visible to users and I have to add additional text so that NVDA will read "Find out more about [slide title]".
I know it's not the best practice, but this is what the client wants and I can't change his mind
Does anyone know a way to make NVDA read additional text on hover when <a> has its own text? Perhaps there is a way around this

https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere

I mean… Who is your client's audience? If blind people (which using of NVDA implies), then, how to say it politically correctly… blind people don't hover, because we don't use mice in general. At all. In principle. There are super-mega-rarest cases when an advanced user needs to click physical mouse because otherwise a control is not accessible, or someone turns on mouse echo and wants to explore, but in general… it's a no-no, especially hovering.

Does NVDA read out title attribute?

This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76565822/nvda-screen-reader-not-readinng-visually-hidden-text/76574754#76574754 talks about visually hidden text, but the thinking is exactly the same for aria-label/aria-labelledby. Hence this question is almost a duplicatd of that other question.

Watch out for this common misconception: “If blind people (which using of NVDA implies).” This is not at all true, only 76 % of screen reader users are blind. Others might very well use pointing devices.

Probably due to the need of some vision to control a pointer device, the text being read is the visible text.
76 % of screen reader users are blind, others might still have some vision to use pointer devices, which is why the feature exists.
So there is no trick to force a different text, and it’s a very bad idea to do that, as it would confuse the users who depend on it.
The WCAG’s 2.5.3: Label in Name (Level A), for example, exist for the same reason.
Usually links like “Find out more” work, because they are visually attributable to content close to it, for example to the title of the same card. So this would also apply to cursor tracking users, and you don’t need to do anything more about it.

By default the accessible name is calculated from the text contents of an element, but it can be changed with aria-label or aria-labelledby.
In the example, aria-labelledby is therefore entirely redundant, as both texts are already in the element.
Referencing the element itself doesn’t make sense, and would theoretically force the algorithm to determine the accessible name in an endless loop. It might be ignored.
Firefox calculates this text, which is probably not what you are looking for:

Find Out More about [slide title] about [slide title]

Here are the two valid options:


/* ie9+ */
/* From Scott O’Hara https://www.scottohara.me/blog/2017/04/14/inclusively-hidden.html */
.visually-hidden:not(:focus):not(:active) {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
}
<p><a href="#" role="button">
    Find Out More
    <span class="visually-hidden">about [slide title]</span>
</a></p>

<p><a href="#" aria-label="Find Out More about [slide title]">Find Out More</a></p>



There is a difference between button and link roles. If it takes you somewhere, it’s a link, and role="button" should be avoided.
